# Vitamio generates an error: Native libs .... not exist

Tags: android, streaming, vitamio

I've been trying to mount a streaming Vitamio 4.2.2 but it has not worked for me. I am using the latest version of android studio and I simulate the project in genymotion.
I am very grateful if you can assist me a little about what's going on that error.

Annex the link to the code in Dropbox

[Project Code](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/rczy6a8agq8wmt1/AAAShkwkraX_03Gph0srwsPia?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue in my project. In first versions, after I integrated the lib with gradle, everything was fine, but after several git commits (nothing was changed in project structure) library checker started returning false as a sign, that the library was not found.

The solution for me was not calling 'return' when lib was not found but throwing an exception (I wrote extension for Exception class) and catching it in calling activity. As a result, the exception was not thrown (surprisingly) and the library started launching the video.